# How do I remove emoji from string

Tags: ruby, regex, unicode, emoji

My problem is to remove emoji from a string, but not CJK (Chinese, Japanese, Korean) characters from a string using regex. I tried to use this regex:

```
REGEX = /[^\u1F600-\u1F6FF\s]/i
```

This regex works fine except it also detects the Chinese, Japanese and Korean character where I need those characters. Any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: there are a LOT of emoji - maybe it's better to make a blacklist of characters to remove?

Comment: @dax mostly those Emojis that are in iPhone and Android Keyboard

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Karol S already provided [a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24673322/477037), but the reason might not be clear:

`"\u1F600"` is actually `"\u1F60"` followed by `"0"`:

```
"\u1F60"    # => "ὠ"
"\u1F600"   # => "ὠ0"
```

You have to use curly braces for code points above FFFF:

```
"\u{1F600}" #=> ""
```

Therefore the character class `[\u1F600-\u1F6FF]` is interpreted as `[\u1F60 0-\u1F6F F]`, i.e. it
matches `"\u1F60"`, the range `"0"`..`"\u1F6F"` and `"F"`.

Using curly braces solves the issue:

```
/[\u{1F600}-\u{1F6FF}]/
```

This matches (emoji) characters in these unicode blocks:

- U+1F600..U+1F64F [Emoticons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoticons_(Unicode_block))
- U+1F650..U+1F67F [Ornamental Dingbats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ornamental_Dingbats_(Unicode_block))
- U+1F680..U+1F6FF [Transport and Map Symbols](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_and_Map_Symbols)

---

You can also use [`unpack`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/String.html#method-i-unpack), [`pack`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Array.html#method-i-pack), and [`between?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Comparable.html#method-i-between-3F) to achieve a similar result. This also works for **Ruby 1.8.7** which doesn't support Unicode in regular expressions.

```
s = 'Hi!'
#=> "Hi!\360\237\230\200"

s.unpack('U*').reject{ |e| e.between?(0x1F600, 0x1F6FF) }.pack('U*')
#=> "Hi!"
```

---

Regarding your [Rubular example](http://rubular.com/r/C7HpUmiJjI) – [Emoji](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoji) are single characters:

```
"".length  #=> 1
"".chars   #=> [""]
```

Whereas [kaomoji](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaomoji) are a combination of multiple characters:

```
"^_^".length #=> 3
"^_^".chars  #=> ["^", "_", "^"]
```

Matching these is a very different task (and you should ask that in a separate question).

Comment: I have tried the regex that you provided. and this is the [link](http://rubular.com/r/C7HpUmiJjI) and this is using my regex that I mentioned in the question [link](http://rubular.com/r/cqO6RtTHdZ). It does not work with your regex, mine is working but has problem like I mentioned in the question.

Comment: @kilua those are not [emoji](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoji) but [kaomoji](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaomoji)

Comment: Owh I see, lets just focus on emoji then. Since I am building this to prevent user to submit emoji from IOS/Android to our server. I know that, they can disable it on keyboard (phone) but still on the server side I need to filter it out. Yes, your regex is working fine for emoji tho, but it does not work for other emoticions like the "houese" "town" "animals" "etc". I have removed the kaomoji

Comment: You have to add the appropriate character ranges, e.g. to include [Miscellaneous Symbols And Pictographs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miscellaneous_Symbols_and_Pictographs) start with U+1F300: `/[\u{1F300}-\u{1F6FF}]/`. Karol S already mentioned that.

Comment: Yes, correct. I am using that one right now but seems it didnt cater all the emoji or those miscellaneous thing. You know, I am using MAC OSX, you can do like ctrl + cmd + space, then you can get those emojis + etc. Not all of them are cater by `/[\u{1F300}-\u{1F6FF}]/` any help? Thank you very much

Comment: @kilua I've posted a [follow-up question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24695159/477037)

Comment: Are you sure about `"^_^".length #=> 1`?

Comment: @Stefan this is a great start but doesn't match all of "" ... 
I found this solution in Ruby which seems to work well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16487697/how-to-remove-4-byte-utf-8-characters-in-ruby

Comment: Stefan your edition didn't work for ruby 1.8.7, the between is not taking the number inside the hex range, so it returns false, and then the emoji is not rejected

Comment: @G.I.Joe it does work, `0x1F600` is just another way of writing `128512`.

Comment: no it doesn't, I ran it even your range is repeating the limits

Comment: @G.I.Joe sorry, there was a typo, the upper limit of course has to be `0x1F6FF`

Answer (score 24):

I am using one based on [this script](https://gist.github.com/adamlwatson/9623703).

```
 def strip_emoji(text)
    text = text.force_encoding('utf-8').encode
    clean = ""

    # symbols & pics
    regex = /[\u{1f300}-\u{1f5ff}]/
    clean = text.gsub regex, ""

    # enclosed chars 
    regex = /[\u{2500}-\u{2BEF}]/ # I changed this to exclude chinese char
    clean = clean.gsub regex, ""

    # emoticons
    regex = /[\u{1f600}-\u{1f64f}]/
    clean = clean.gsub regex, ""

    #dingbats
    regex = /[\u{2702}-\u{27b0}]/
    clean = clean.gsub regex, ""
  end
```

Results:

```
irb> strip_emoji("☂❤华み원❤")
=> "华み원"
```

Comment: great answer.. saves my day.. !! :)

Comment: This worked well for me.  I created a EmojiStripper concern that uses a before_validation callback to strip emojis from all string fields before validation is executed.  That results in all emojis being stripped before it is saved to the DB.

Comment: WARNING: THE CODE IN THIS ANSWER WILL NOT REMOVE ALL EMOJIS. It removes simple emojis fine, but it does not fully remove multi code points emojis correctly, such as ‍‍‍or ☸️.

Answer (score 20):

This regex matches all 845 emoji, taken from [Emoji unicode characters for use on the web](http://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode#block-6c-other-additional-symbols):

```
[\u{203C}\u{2049}\u{20E3}\u{2122}\u{2139}\u{2194}-\u{2199}\u{21A9}-\u{21AA}\u{231A}-\u{231B}\u{23E9}-\u{23EC}\u{23F0}\u{23F3}\u{24C2}\u{25AA}-\u{25AB}\u{25B6}\u{25C0}\u{25FB}-\u{25FE}\u{2600}-\u{2601}\u{260E}\u{2611}\u{2614}-\u{2615}\u{261D}\u{263A}\u{2648}-\u{2653}\u{2660}\u{2663}\u{2665}-\u{2666}\u{2668}\u{267B}\u{267F}\u{2693}\u{26A0}-\u{26A1}\u{26AA}-\u{26AB}\u{26BD}-\u{26BE}\u{26C4}-\u{26C5}\u{26CE}\u{26D4}\u{26EA}\u{26F2}-\u{26F3}\u{26F5}\u{26FA}\u{26FD}\u{2702}\u{2705}\u{2708}-\u{270C}\u{270F}\u{2712}\u{2714}\u{2716}\u{2728}\u{2733}-\u{2734}\u{2744}\u{2747}\u{274C}\u{274E}\u{2753}-\u{2755}\u{2757}\u{2764}\u{2795}-\u{2797}\u{27A1}\u{27B0}\u{2934}-\u{2935}\u{2B05}-\u{2B07}\u{2B1B}-\u{2B1C}\u{2B50}\u{2B55}\u{3030}\u{303D}\u{3297}\u{3299}\u{1F004}\u{1F0CF}\u{1F170}-\u{1F171}\u{1F17E}-\u{1F17F}\u{1F18E}\u{1F191}-\u{1F19A}\u{1F1E7}-\u{1F1EC}\u{1F1EE}-\u{1F1F0}\u{1F1F3}\u{1F1F5}\u{1F1F7}-\u{1F1FA}\u{1F201}-\u{1F202}\u{1F21A}\u{1F22F}\u{1F232}-\u{1F23A}\u{1F250}-\u{1F251}\u{1F300}-\u{1F320}\u{1F330}-\u{1F335}\u{1F337}-\u{1F37C}\u{1F380}-\u{1F393}\u{1F3A0}-\u{1F3C4}\u{1F3C6}-\u{1F3CA}\u{1F3E0}-\u{1F3F0}\u{1F400}-\u{1F43E}\u{1F440}\u{1F442}-\u{1F4F7}\u{1F4F9}-\u{1F4FC}\u{1F500}-\u{1F507}\u{1F509}-\u{1F53D}\u{1F550}-\u{1F567}\u{1F5FB}-\u{1F640}\u{1F645}-\u{1F64F}\u{1F680}-\u{1F68A}]
```

I generated this regex directly from the raw list of Unicode emoji. The algorithm is here: https://github.com/franklsf95/ruby-emoji-regex.

Example usage:

```
regex = /[\u{203C}\u{2049}\u{20E3}\u{2122}\u{2139}\u{2194}-\u{2199}\u{21A9}-\u{21AA}\u{231A}-\u{231B}\u{23E9}-\u{23EC}\u{23F0}\u{23F3}\u{24C2}\u{25AA}-\u{25AB}\u{25B6}\u{25C0}\u{25FB}-\u{25FE}\u{2600}-\u{2601}\u{260E}\u{2611}\u{2614}-\u{2615}\u{261D}\u{263A}\u{2648}-\u{2653}\u{2660}\u{2663}\u{2665}-\u{2666}\u{2668}\u{267B}\u{267F}\u{2693}\u{26A0}-\u{26A1}\u{26AA}-\u{26AB}\u{26BD}-\u{26BE}\u{26C4}-\u{26C5}\u{26CE}\u{26D4}\u{26EA}\u{26F2}-\u{26F3}\u{26F5}\u{26FA}\u{26FD}\u{2702}\u{2705}\u{2708}-\u{270C}\u{270F}\u{2712}\u{2714}\u{2716}\u{2728}\u{2733}-\u{2734}\u{2744}\u{2747}\u{274C}\u{274E}\u{2753}-\u{2755}\u{2757}\u{2764}\u{2795}-\u{2797}\u{27A1}\u{27B0}\u{2934}-\u{2935}\u{2B05}-\u{2B07}\u{2B1B}-\u{2B1C}\u{2B50}\u{2B55}\u{3030}\u{303D}\u{3297}\u{3299}\u{1F004}\u{1F0CF}\u{1F170}-\u{1F171}\u{1F17E}-\u{1F17F}\u{1F18E}\u{1F191}-\u{1F19A}\u{1F1E7}-\u{1F1EC}\u{1F1EE}-\u{1F1F0}\u{1F1F3}\u{1F1F5}\u{1F1F7}-\u{1F1FA}\u{1F201}-\u{1F202}\u{1F21A}\u{1F22F}\u{1F232}-\u{1F23A}\u{1F250}-\u{1F251}\u{1F300}-\u{1F320}\u{1F330}-\u{1F335}\u{1F337}-\u{1F37C}\u{1F380}-\u{1F393}\u{1F3A0}-\u{1F3C4}\u{1F3C6}-\u{1F3CA}\u{1F3E0}-\u{1F3F0}\u{1F400}-\u{1F43E}\u{1F440}\u{1F442}-\u{1F4F7}\u{1F4F9}-\u{1F4FC}\u{1F500}-\u{1F507}\u{1F509}-\u{1F53D}\u{1F550}-\u{1F567}\u{1F5FB}-\u{1F640}\u{1F645}-\u{1F64F}\u{1F680}-\u{1F68A}]/
str = "I am a string with emoji  and other Unicode characters 比如中文."
str.gsub regex, ''
# "I am a string with emoji  and other Unicode characters 比如中文."
```

Other Unicode characters, such as Asian characters, are preserved.

EDIT: I udpated the regex to exclude ASCII numbers and symbols. See comments for details.

Comment: Huh, I pasted this into rubular and found that it matched numbers, too

Comment: @rmosolgo Thanks for catching this! I have excluded numbers and other ASCII characters from the emoji. The reason numbers were included is that some emoji are of the form 8⃣ (`U+0038 U+20E3`). I manually removed those ASCII codes.

Answer (score 17):

Most of the answers in this thread don't remove all emojis correctly. They remove simple emojis like  fine. But they won't fully remove multi code point emojis like ‍‍‍ or ☸️, leaving some residual unicode code points behind.

You could use a gem like [unicode-emoji](https://github.com/janlelis/unicode-emoji) to get the latest emoji regexes, but if you find this overkill the following code might be a good enough solution:

```
text.gsub(/[^[:alnum:][:blank:][:punct:]]/, '').squeeze(' ').strip
```

This will remove any emoji or weird-unicody-like character that is not a basic alphanum/punct/blank.

Answer (score 11):

```
REGEX = /[^\u{1F600}-\u{1F6FF}\s]/
```

or

```
REGEX = /[\u{1F600}-\u{1F6FF}\s]/
REGEX = /[\u{1F600}-\u{1F6FF}]/
REGEX = /[^\u{1F600}-\u{1F6FF}]/
```

because your original regex seems to indicate you try to find everything that is not an amoji and not a whitespace and I don't know why would you want to do it.

Also:

- the emoji are 1F300-1F6FF rather than 1F600-1F6FF; you may want to change that
- if you want to remove all astral characters (for example you deal with a software that doesn't support all of Unicode), you should use 10000-10FFFF.

EDIT: You almost certainly want `REGEX = /[\u{1F600}-\u{1F6FF}]/` or similar. Your original regex matched everything that is not a whitespace, and not in range `0-\u1F6F`. Since spaces are whitespace, and English letters are in range `0-\u1F6F`, and Chinese characters are in neither, the regex matched Chinese characters and removed them.

Comment: Thanks for replied, I have tried all your regex in rubular, none of them are working. This is mine [link](http://rubular.com/r/cqO6RtTHdZ) but it has problem that I stated in question...

Comment: Your sample list doesn't contain any [emoji](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoji), it contains [kaomoji](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaomoji). Kaomoji are made from mix of letters and symbols, you can't remove them with a simple regex.

Comment: ya my mistake, now I understand how it works... Thanks for your replied

Comment: Any idea why my regex doesn't compile? I'm doing `ls | perl -e 'print if /[^\u{1F600}-\u{1F6FF}\s]/'` to find filenames containing emoji.

Comment: @SridharSarnobat Assuming your system's locale is UTF-8, you need to tell Perl to use UTF-8 on standard I/O: `ls | perl -CSD -ne 'print if /[^\u{1F600}-\u{1F6FF}\s]/'`

Comment: @KarolS thanks, I need to try this when I get home!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of removing Emoji characters, you can only include alphabets and numbers. A simple tr should do the trick, `.tr('^A-Za-z0-9', '')`. Of course this will remove all punctuation, but you can always modify the regex to suit your specific condition.

Answer (score 1):

This very short [Regex](http://rubular.com/r/1VNLrztfxj) covers all Emoji in [getemoji.com](https://getemoji.com/) so far:

```
[\u{1F300}-\u{1F5FF}|\u{1F1E6}-\u{1F1FF}|\u{2700}-\u{27BF}|\u{1F900}-\u{1F9FF}|\u{1F600}-\u{1F64F}|\u{1F680}-\u{1F6FF}|\u{2600}-\u{26FF}]
```

Comment: Same regexp using `\U` (for Python, Postgres, etc.): `[\U0001F300-\U0001F5FF|\U0001F1E6-\U0001F1FF|\U00002700-\U000027BF|\U0001F900-\U0001F9FF|\U0001F600-\U0001F64F|\U0001F680-\U0001F6FF|\U00002600-\U000026FF]`

Answer (score 1):

CARE the answer from Aray have some side effects.

```
"-".gsub(/[^\p{L}\s]+/, '').squeeze(' ').strip
=> ""
```

even when this is suppose to be a simple minus (-)

Answer (score 0):

I converted the RegEx from the RUBY project above to a JavaScript friendly RegEx:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Emoji symbols character sets (added \s and +)
    /// Unicode with עברית Delete the emoji to match 
    /// https://regex101.com/r/jP5jC5/3
    /// https://github.com/franklsf95/ruby-emoji-regex
    /// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24672834/how-do-i-remove-emoji-from-string
    /// </summary>
    public const string Emoji = @"^[\s\u00A9\u00AE\u203C\u2049\u2122\u2139\u2194-\u2199\u21A9-\u21AA\u231A-\u231B\u2328\u23CF\u23E9-\u23F3\u23F8-\u23FA\u24C2\u25AA-\u25AB\u25B6\u25C0\u25FB-\u25FE\u2600-\u2604\u260E\u2611\u2614-\u2615\u2618\u261D\u2620\u2622-\u2623\u2626\u262A\u262E-\u262F\u2638-\u263A\u2648-\u2653\u2660\u2663\u2665-\u2666\u2668\u267B\u267F\u2692-\u2694\u2696-\u2697\u2699\u269B-\u269C\u26A0-\u26A1\u26AA-\u26AB\u26B0-\u26B1\u26BD-\u26BE\u26C4-\u26C5\u26C8\u26CE-\u26CF\u26D1\u26D3-\u26D4\u26E9-\u26EA\u26F0-\u26F5\u26F7-\u26FA\u26FD\u2702\u2705\u2708-\u270D\u270F\u2712\u2714\u2716\u271D\u2721\u2728\u2733-\u2734\u2744\u2747\u274C\u274E\u2753-\u2755\u2757\u2763-\u2764\u2795-\u2797\u27A1\u27B0\u27BF\u2934-\u2935\u2B05-\u2B07\u2B1B-\u2B1C\u2B50\u2B55\u3030\u303D\u3297\u3299\u1F004\u1F0CF\u1F170-\u1F171\u1F17E-\u1F17F\u1F18E\u1F191-\u1F19A\u1F201-\u1F202\u1F21A\u1F22F\u1F232-\u1F23A\u1F250-\u1F251\u1F300-\u1F321\u1F324-\u1F393\u1F396-\u1F397\u1F399-\u1F39B\u1F39E-\u1F3F0\u1F3F3-\u1F3F5\u1F3F7-\u1F4FD\u1F4FF-\u1F53D\u1F549-\u1F54E\u1F550-\u1F567\u1F56F-\u1F570\u1F573-\u1F579\u1F587\u1F58A-\u1F58D\u1F590\u1F595-\u1F596\u1F5A5\u1F5A8\u1F5B1-\u1F5B2\u1F5BC\u1F5C2-\u1F5C4\u1F5D1-\u1F5D3\u1F5DC-\u1F5DE\u1F5E1\u1F5E3\u1F5EF\u1F5F3\u1F5FA-\u1F64F\u1F680-\u1F6C5\u1F6CB-\u1F6D0\u1F6E0-\u1F6E5\u1F6E9\u1F6EB-\u1F6EC\u1F6F0\u1F6F3\u1F910-\u1F918\u1F980-\u1F984\u1F9C0}]+$";
```

Usage:

```
if (!Regex.IsMatch(vm.NameFull, RegExKeys.Emoji)) // Match means no Emoji was found
```

Answer (score 0):

In Android | Kotlin you can use this extension function to remove all emojis from String

```
fun String.removeEmojis(): String = Pattern.compile("[^\\p{L}\\s]+")
    .matcher(this).replaceAll("")
```

Sample :

```
val result = "Hi emojis      removed".removeEmojis()
output => "Hi emojis removed"
```

Answer (score -1):

```
         // method to remove emoji from string
    public static String remove_emoji(String text){
                    String updated_text="";
                    for (int i=0;i<text.length();i++){
                        if(text.substring(i,i+1).matches("[\\x00-\\x7F]+")){
             // regex [\\x00-\\x7F]+ will check it contains emoji symbol or not,if it matches it means its not the emoji symbol            

updated_text=updated_text+text.substring(i,i+1);
                        }
                    }
                    return updated_text;
                }
```

Comment: Providing more information about why this solves the problem can be a great way to improve your answer and help the users with the same problem