# How can I match emoji with an R regex?

Tags: r, regex, emoji, utf-16

I want to determine which elements of my vector contain emoji:

```
x = c('', 'no', '', '', 'no', '', '䨺', '감사')
x
# [1] "\U0001f602" "no"         "\U0001f379" "\U0001f600" "no"         "\U0001f61b" "䨺"         "감사"
```

Related posts only cover other languages, and because mostly they refer to specialized libraries, I couldn't figure out a way to translate to R:

- [What is the regex to extract all the emojis from a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24840667/what-is-the-regex-to-extract-all-the-emojis-from-a-string)
- [How do I remove emoji from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24672834/how-do-i-remove-emoji-from-string)
- [replace emoji unicode symbol using regexp in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22006218/replace-emoji-unicode-symbol-using-regexp-in-javascript)
- [Regular expression matching emoji in Mac OS X / iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24695159/regular-expression-matching-emoji-in-mac-os-x-ios)
- [remove unicode emoji using re in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26568722/remove-unicode-emoji-using-re-in-python)

The second looked very promising, but alas (not fixed by supplying `perl = TRUE`):

```
x[grepl('[\u{1F600}-\u{1F6FF}]', x)]
```

> Error: invalid \u{xxxx} sequence (line 1)

Similar issues come about from other questions. How can we match emoji in R?

Comment: capital U ? (3 to go)

Comment: @SymbolixAU oh my! well that's embarassing orz

Comment: You'll also want to reduce the range to capture the 'drink' emoji too :)

Comment: @SymbolixAU I guess it should start from 1F347? Are everything inbetween those emoji? http://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html

Comment: no idea, but from your link it looks like it

Comment: @SymbolixAU I see [1F33E](http://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html#1f468_200d_1f33e), but it looks like it's a block component?

Comment: Actually, I see all the way down to 1F300 (cyclone)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am converting the encoding to UTF-8 to compare the UTF-8 value of emoji's value with all the emoji's value in `remoji` library which is in UTF-8. I am using the `stringr` library to find the position of emoji's in the vector. One is free to use grep or any other function.

**1st Method:**

```r
library(stringr)
xvect = c('', 'no', '', '', 'no', '')

Encoding(xvect) <- "UTF-8"

which(str_detect(xvect,"[^[:ascii:]]"))
# [1] 1 3 4 6
```

Here 1,3,4 and 6 are emoji's character in this case.

**Edited :**

**2nd Method:**
Install a GitHub package called `remoji`. Since we have already converted the emoji items into **UTF**-8. we can now compare the UTF-**8** values of all the emoji's present in the emoji library. Use `trimws` to remove the whitespaces

```r
library(remoji) # remotes::install_github("richfitz/remoji")
emj <- emoji(list_emoji(), TRUE)
which(xvect %in% trimws(emj))
# [1] 1 3 4 6
```

Both of the above methods are not full proof and **first method assumes that there are no any ascii characters other than emojis in the vector** and **second method relies on the library information of `remoji`. In case where the a certain emoji information is not present in the library, the last command may yield a FALSE instead of TRUE**.

**Final Edit:**

As per the discussion amongst OP(**@MichaelChirico**) and **@SymbolixAU**. Thanks to both of them it seems the problem with small typo of capital U. The new regex is `xvect[grepl('[\U{1F300}-\U{1F6FF}]', xvect)]` . The range in the character class is taken from F300 to F6FF. One can off course change this range to a new range in cases where an emoji lies outside this range. This may not be the complete list and over the period of time these ranges may keep increasing/changing.

Comment: It's a nice suggestion, but there are _many_ non-ASCII characters in my vector which are not emoji. I've updated my post to reflect this.

Comment: @MichaelChirico Yeah I know both of the above methods have some limitations, I am also trying to find if there are any better alternatives in R. Strange even after the new character additions both of the above commands are giving right results. I am not sure why

Comment: The typo-corrected & expanded version from the comments seems to be doing pretty well: `x[grepl('[\U{1F300}-\u{1F6FF}]', x)]`