# Scrape only Tweets with Emojis in R

Tags: r, web-scraping

I have been working on a project related to Sentiment Analysis on Emojis. And I only want tweets with emojis in them and I don't want to do it manually So, is there any way that I could make some changes in the below code that will result only in the tweets that have emoticons in them. So, let's say that if I scrape 100 tweets, those 100 tweets must have some kind of emojis with some text. Any help will be highly appreciated.

For example, I only want tweets like this:

```
when is @McDonalds_SA gonna let us add spicy sauce on our veg burgers when we order on MrD or Uber eats
```

Code:

```
get_token() # Connects with Twitter API
Uber <- search_tweets("uber", n = 100, lang = "en")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** I assume you're not looking for *all* emoji, since they include quite common characters:

[image]

(from https://unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/emoji/emoji-data.txt)

##### Unicode library

To get the Unicode block for one or more characters, we can use the *Unicode* library:

```
library("Unicode") # install.packages("Unicode")
```

A few examples:

```
> "" |> utf8ToInt() |> u_char_properties("Block")

            Block
U+1F60E Emoticons
```

```
> "‍‍" |> utf8ToInt() |> u_char_properties("Block")

                                  Block
1 Miscellaneous Symbols and Pictographs
2                   General Punctuation
3 Miscellaneous Symbols and Pictographs
4                   General Punctuation
5 Miscellaneous Symbols and Pictographs
```

```
> "" |> utf8ToInt() |> u_char_properties("Block")

                                       Block
U+1F910 Supplemental Symbols and Pictographs
```

```
> "✅" |> utf8ToInt() |> u_char_properties("Block")

          Block
U+2705 Dingbats
```

```
> "☝️" |> utf8ToInt() |> u_char_properties("Block")

                       Block
U+261D Miscellaneous Symbols
U+FE0F   Variation Selectors
```

```
> "☎️" |> utf8ToInt() |> u_char_properties("Block")

                       Block
U+260E Miscellaneous Symbols
U+FE0F   Variation Selectors
```

```
> "♍" |> utf8ToInt() |> u_char_properties("Block")

                       Block
U+264D Miscellaneous Symbols
```

```
> "" |> utf8ToInt() |> u_char_properties("Block")

                                        Block
U+1FAC3    Symbols and Pictographs Extended-A
U+1F3FD Miscellaneous Symbols and Pictographs
```

```
> "" |> utf8ToInt() |> u_char_properties("Block")

                            Block
U+1F682 Transport and Map Symbols
```

Matching all emoji-like characters could be done like this:

```
blocks <- c("Emoticons",
            "Miscellaneous Symbols and Pictographs",
            "Supplemental Symbols and Pictographs",
            "Dingbats",
            "Miscellaneous Symbols",
            "Symbols and Pictographs Extended-A",
            "Transport and Map Symbols")
```

```
> "" |> utf8ToInt() |> u_char_properties("Block") |> unlist() |> intersect(blocks) |> length() > 0
[1] TRUE
```

```
> "‍‍" |> utf8ToInt() |> u_char_properties("Block") |> unlist() |> intersect(blocks) |> length() > 0
[1] TRUE
```

```
> "" |> utf8ToInt() |> u_char_properties("Block") |> unlist() |> intersect(blocks) |> length() > 0
[1] TRUE
```

```
> "☎️" |> utf8ToInt() |> u_char_properties("Block") |> unlist() |> intersect(blocks) |> length() > 0
[1] TRUE
```

```
> "♍" |> utf8ToInt() |> u_char_properties("Block") |> unlist() |> intersect(blocks) |> length() > 0
[1] TRUE
```

```
> "" |> utf8ToInt() |> u_char_properties("Block") |> unlist() |> intersect(blocks) |> length() > 0
[1] TRUE
```

```
> "" |> utf8ToInt() |> u_char_properties("Block") |> unlist() |> intersect(blocks) |> length() > 0
[1] TRUE
```

```
> "#" |> utf8ToInt() |> u_char_properties("Block") |> unlist() |> intersect(blocks) |> length() > 0
[1] FALSE
```

##### Integrating into your code

```
library(rtweet)
library(dplyr)

get_token() # Connects with Twitter API
Uber <- search_tweets("uber", n = 100, lang = "en")

Uber_filtered <- Uber %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  filter(text |> utf8ToInt() |> u_char_properties("Block") |> unlist() |> intersect(blocks) |> length() > 0)
```

Comment: There is an error in the filter part where it says: object 'blocks' not found.

Comment: @M.TalhaBinAsif apologies, I forgot to copy that vector to SO. I've added it now.

Answer (score -1):

Just a simple solution based on a regex of all emojis. Let me know if this works.

```r
library(rtweet)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

get_token()
uber <- search_tweets("uber", n = 2000, lang = "en")
emoji_regex <- "||||☺️||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||✨||||||||||||||||||||||✊|✌️||✋|✋||||||||☝️|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||❤️|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||⭐|☀️|⛅|☁️|⚡|☔|❄️|⛄||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||☎️|☎️|||||||||||||||⏳|⌛|⏰|⌚||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||✉️|✉️|||||||||||||||||||||||||✂️|||✒️|✏️|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||⚽|⚾️|||||⛳|||||||||||☕||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||⛪|||||||⛺||||||||||||⛲|||⛵|⛵|||⚓||✈️||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||⚠️|||⛽||||♨️|||||||||||||||||1️⃣|2️⃣|3️⃣|4️⃣|5️⃣|6️⃣|7️⃣|8️⃣|9️⃣|0️⃣|||#️⃣||⬆️|⬇️|⬅️|➡️||||↗️|↖️|↘️|↙️|↔️|↕️||◀️|▶️|||↩️|↪️|ℹ️|⏪|⏩|⏫|⏬|⤵️|⤴️||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||️|♿||️||️|Ⓜ️||||||㊙️|㊗️||||||||||||⛔|✳️|❇️|❎|✅|✴️|||||️|️||️||➿|♻️|♈|♉|♊|♋|♌|♍|♎|♏|♐|♑|♒|♓|⛎||||||©️|®️|™️|❌|‼️|⁉️|❗|❗|❓|❕|❔|⭕|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||✖️|➕|➖|➗|♠️|♥️|♣️|♦️|||✔️|☑️|||➰|〰️|〽️||◼️|◻️|◾|◽|▪️|▫️||||⚫|⚪||||⬜|⬛||||"
filter(uber, str_detect(text, emoji_regex))
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for replying but I am only looking to get only the tweets with emojis. Like all the tweets must have emojis in them. I tried your code but it is returning all kinds of tweets, with plain text and tweets with emojis.

Comment: Ok, how about my edits?

Comment: It gives this error after "emj <- emoji(list_emoji(), TRUE)" this line. Error:emj <- emoji(list_emoji(), TRUE).

Comment: Try following the remoji install instructions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43359066/how-can-i-match-emoji-with-an-r-regex

Comment: No, there is no difference :(

Comment: Ok, I pasted the regex for you.