# Strip emojis from Telegram bot update

Tags: boost, unicode, c++03, boost-regex, boost-propertytree

I want to remove the emojis from a json Telegram bot update parsed with boost property tree

I tried to use the regex pattern from this answer and a few others but I'm not sure how to get them to work in C++ (the below causes a crash):
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24674266/2212021

```
"message":{
   "message_id":123,
   "from":{
      "id":12345,
      "first_name":"name",
      "username":"username"
   },
   "chat":{
      "id":12345,
      "first_name":"name",
      "username":"username",
      "type":"private"
   },
   "date":1478144459,
   "text":"this is \ud83d\udca9 a sentence"
}
```

```
BOOST_FOREACH(const boost::property_tree::ptree::value_type& child, jsontree.get_child("result"))
{

        std::string message(child.second.get<std::string>("message.text").c_str());

        boost::regex exp("/[\u{1F600}-\u{1F6FF}]/");
        std::string message_clean = regex_replace(message, exp, "");

        ...
}
```

> Exception thrown at 0x00007FF87C1C7788 in
>   CrysisWarsDedicatedServer.exe: Microsoft C++ exception:
>   boost::exception_detail::clone_impl > at memory location 0x000000001003F138. Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF87C1C7788 in CrysisWarsDedicatedServer.exe: Microsoft C++
>   exception:
>   boost::exception_detail::clone_impl > at memory location 0x000000001003F138.

Comment: This question could use some more details: I'm presuming `regex` is actually `boost::regex`. What do you mean when you can't get it to work? Does it compile? Does it crash while running? Or does `message_clean` not give you the desired result (e.g. all the emojis are still in the string)? Have you tried using a simpler regex (e.g. remove all numbers) to ensure `regex_replace` is working correctly? What version of `boost` are you using?

Comment: Apologies; yes, boost::regex. The problem is that it crashes and the version is boost 1.55

Comment: How does it crash, where?

Comment: Had a go at attaching to the process. edited main post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is using `.c_str()` on a byte array with arbitrary text encoding. There's no need, so don't do it.

Next, `'\u'` is not a valid C++ character escape. Did you mean `'\\u'`?

Finally, make sure Boost Regex is [compiled with Unicode support](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/ref/non_std_strings/icu.html) and use the appropriate functions.

After spending some time with those documentation pages and also

- http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html and
- http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f4a9/index.htm

I came up with

**<kbd>[Live On Wandbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/FPVL7Cm5p09e1kJO)</kbd>**

```
//#define BOOST_HAS_ICU
#include <boost/property_tree/json_parser.hpp>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
#include <boost/regex/icu.hpp>
#include <iostream>
std::string asUtf8(icu::UnicodeString const& ustr);

std::string sample = R"(
{
    "message":{
       "message_id":123,
       "from":{
          "id":12345,
          "first_name":"name",
          "username":"username"
       },
       "chat":{
          "id":12345,
          "first_name":"name",
          "username":"username",
          "type":"private"
       },
       "date":1478144459,
       "text":"this is \ud83d\udca9 a sentence"
    }
}
)";

int main() {

    boost::property_tree::ptree pt;
    {
        std::istringstream iss(sample);
        read_json(iss, pt);
    }
    auto umessage       = icu::UnicodeString::fromUTF8(pt.get("message.text", ""));
    boost::u32regex exp = boost::make_u32regex("\\p{So}");

    auto clean = boost::u32regex_replace(umessage, exp, UnicodeString::fromUTF8("<symbol>"));

    std::cout << asUtf8(clean) << "\n";
}

std::string asUtf8(icu::UnicodeString const& ustr) {
    std::string r;
    {
        icu::StringByteSink<std::string> bs(&r);
        ustr.toUTF8(bs);
    }

    return r;
}
```

This prints:

```
this is <symbol> a sentence
```

Comment: Live demo on [Melpon Wandbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/FPVL7Cm5p09e1kJO)