# regex to remove all unicode emojis in QT5

Tags: regex, unicode, qt5

I need to remove all unicode emojis from a QString, so I tried to write a regex:

```
    QRegularExpression uTF8Emojis("([\\xD83D][\\xDE00-\\xDFFF])+");
```

but that does not detect anything...

Comment: Try `"[\\x{1F600}-\\x{1F7FF}]+"`. However, maybe the emojis you want to remove are from another Unicode range.

Comment: this syntax seems to work, thanks!

Comment: Does this simpler regex works in qt5 as well as in javascript? https://stackoverflow.com/a/64007175/8186898

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Qt5 `QRegularExpression` is PCRE-powered, you may use the whole code points for the characters inside `\x{...}` notation, no need to define these emojis as a sequence of bytes:

```
"[\\x{1F600}-\\x{1F7FF}]+"
```

You may use [this online converter](http://r12a.github.io/apps/conversion/): paste `\uD83D\uDE00-\uD83D\uDFFF` into the *JavaScript* field, and click *Convert* to get the right codes in the *U+hex* field.

Comment: Some of the astral characters are not covered in that range, i will recommend 10000-10FFFF. according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24672834/how-do-i-remove-emoji-from-string/24673322#24673322

Comment: @e.jahandar: Yes, if there can be no astral chars in the input that one wants to keep. Emojis are numerous, there are more ranges to cover. I just converted OP regex to QT usable form.

Answer (score 0):

I use this in my QRegularExpression
https://github.com/mathiasbynens/rgi-emoji-regex-pattern/blob/main/dist/emoji-14.0/java.txt
And it works just fine
And author update regexp regularly with recent emojis

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31915585)