# How to remove emojis from an XML string or file whether they are encoded or not

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri, emoji

I want to remove emojis from XML files. 
A typical example string could be something like:

```
<a> grêve &#55357;&#56628; SNCF  ➡️</a>
```

I want to have only:

```
<a>grêve SNCF</a>
```

I tried to use Nokogiri's `noent` option and some filters after the parse stage, but `to_xml` returns the emojis as HTML entities and I do not detect them anymore. 
It returns something like:

```
<a>&#x1F92C; gr&#xEA;ve  SNCF &#x1F534; &#x27A1;&#xFE0F;</a>
```

```rb
require 'nokogiri'

xml = Nokogiri::XML(%{
  <root>
    <aliens>
      <alien>
        <name>
           grêve &#55357;&#56628; SNCF  ➡️
        </name>
      </alien>
    </aliens>
  </root>
}) do |config|
  config.noent
end

puts xml

# emoticons
clean_xml_str = xml.to_xml
  .unpack('U*')
  .reject{ |e|
    # emoticons block
    e.between?(0x1F600, 0x1F6FF)  ||
    # basic block - control characters
    e.between?(0x0000, 0x001F) ||
    # Private Use Area
    e.between?(0xE000, 0xF8FF)
  }
  .pack('U*')

puts clean_xml_str
```

See [sandbox on repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/UniformPassionateDesignmethod) for more information.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I remove emoji from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24672834/how-do-i-remove-emoji-from-string)

Comment: I already did that `e.between` part

Answer (score 0):

You're asking Nokogiri to do something that isn't really its job. Nokogiri is supposed to parse valid XML and [those characters seem to be valid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valid_characters_in_XML). In these situations we're forced to pre-process the file, then hand it off. The same thing happens with pathologically damaged XML or HTML; It's dirty and we feel dirty doing it, but it's entirely acceptable rather than jump through hoops after the fact.

I'd use a pattern, or a couple, to remove any characters out of the normal ASCII range, or whatever range you deem acceptable prior to passing the XML on to Nokogiri. For a quick and dirty example this strips anything out of the ASCII range but you'll want to fine-tune it as it's munging `ê`:

```rb
'<a> grêve &#55357;&#56628; SNCF  ➡️</a>'.gsub(/[^\x20-\x7e]+/, '')
# => "<a> grve &#55357;&#56628; SNCF  </a>"
```

or:

```rb
'<a> grêve &#55357;&#56628; SNCF  ➡️</a>'.gsub(/[^[:ascii:]]+/, '')
# => "<a> grve &#55357;&#56628; SNCF  </a>"
```

Simply add the encoded strings into the patterns, or run a second pass to handle them. Ruby's [Regexp documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Regexp.html) will help you fine-tune it.

As far as the solution in "[How do I remove emoji from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24672834/how-do-i-remove-emoji-from-string)", it will also work, but it's going to be slower because it's iterating through every character. `gsub` with a pattern will pass it off to Ruby's regular expression engine which, if you pass it the entire XML file, will run much faster.

Comment: Thanks for that detailed response, it makes sense, I'll test all this soon ( and try to remember to follow up the results here :) )

Comment: If, by "follow up the results", you mean summarize or showing what you did, please don't. There are rare occasions when it's helpful but in general it confuses others looking for a similar solution. Otherwise see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers.