# Regex that accepts foreign characters except emojis

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex

I'm using `/[a-zA-Z0-9０-９Ａ-ｚ]/g` as a regex but it doesn't accept the test case if it doesn't have a digit.

What regex can I use? I'm using it in React so `\p{L}` doesn't work for me.

test case

```
北海道札幌市中央区以下に掲載がない場合
北海道札幌市中央区以下に掲載がない場合
北海道札幌市中央区大通西
１～１９丁目
央区北二条西（１～１９丁目）
北海道札幌市中央区以下に掲載がない場合
北海道札幌市中央区大通西（１～１９丁目）
서울특별시 종로구 사직로3길 23, 102동 304호 홍길동 귀하 30174
18-Molave St, Makati City
北海道札幌市中央区大通東
: (false)
```

Comment: Hello there is another question which is same and answered https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24672834/how-do-i-remove-emoji-from-string

Comment: When you say you want it to accept foreign characters except for emoji, do you mean that if a string contains an emoji, you want it to not match and for it to match otherwise or that you want to extract non-emoji characters from a string?